# Skip Authentication for /login in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to skip the authentication for the /login request.

In my ServerApplication, I wrote this method to achieve it:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
        }
    }
```

But, I'm getting this response now (while trying to hit the **/login** endpoint, no matter what arguments/headers I pass):

```
{
  "timestamp": 1493881871867,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/login"
}
```

Tried `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,` and several other similar solutions, but still getting the same response.

Also created an endpoint for /login, but that's not getting hit:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody) {
        System.out.println("DO I EVEN REACH HERE?");
        return null;
    }
```

I'm very new to Spring and can't figure out the mistake I'm doing here. Any help?

Comment: `.antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()` ? btw do you really send JSON? it could b e just content type is wrong.

Comment: didn't work.. :(

Comment: Try adding `.anyRequest();` to your call.
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll.anyRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

Error message is;

```
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Which means you posting to `/login` via a html form. but your `login` endpoint doesn't accept form params. Change the `login` endpoint as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.println("DO I EVEN REACH HERE?");
    return null;
}
```